# Java container options for non HTTP worloads

Tags: java, http, tomcat, ejb, containers

In our current production stack we have different types of workloads, many of them HTTP related and running in Tomcat containers, but we also have some other kind of workloads, which have been split into self managed standalone applications and war files that fire up cron-like jobs, queue (MQTT & SNS) listeners and, daemon kind of servers for IoT devices which have tons of different TCP protocols.

We are aware that standalone apps are not easy to manage and running the above kind of services in Tomcat containers is not entirely correct too, so I'm asking what are the best practices for running such services and/or what are the nowadays containers for these purposes.

I know that EJBs might work for some of these scenarios, but could be quite an overhead to use them, so I'm trying to find more options.

PS: 99% of of software is built in Java, so that's a heavy constraint for our possible choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might want a full-blown [ESB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) (Enterprise Service Bus), though that's probably overkill.

If you look at the [Products section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus#Products) of the Wikipedia page linked above, you'll find multiple options.

However, if you're just looking for the communication layer, rather than a full ESB, you could use something like [Apache CXF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_CXF), which is used by the [Apache ServiceMix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_ServiceMix) ESB.

Haven't used it myself, but it supports multiple transport layers, such as HTTP, JMS, WebSocket, and CORBA, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Indeed an ESB might me a good option, not just the transport layer, I'll have to study the available ones.